# SF_TARGET_ORG seems empty during deployment, why?

Tags: salesforcedx, cicd, sf-cli

In my connected app, I want to set the `<oauthClientCredentialUser>scratchOrgUserName</oauthClientCredentialUser>` to my current user during deployment.

Therefore I use the replacement feature.

```
"replacements": [
  {
    "filename": "force-app/main/default/connectedApps/MyApp.connectedApp-meta.xml",
    "stringToReplace": "scratchOrgUserName",
    "replaceWithEnv": "SF_TARGET_ORG"
  }
]
```

the command

```
sf config get target-org
```

returns

```
Get Config
==================================================
| Name       Value                         Success 
| ────────── ───────────────────────────── ─────── 
| target-org test-fvm8ljytebmc@example.com true
```

but running

```
sf project deploy start
```

throws:

> Error (1): Component conversion failed: "SF_TARGET_ORG" is in
> sfdx-project.json as a value for "replaceWithEnv" property, but it's
> not set in your environment.

it's the same environment (`sf project deploy start` also knows where to deploy), so the env var should be defined, what am I missing?